# How to send message to the rabbitmq queue using spring integration java DSL

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-rabbit, spring-integration-amqp

I wrote simple sample to read text from console and send it to the rabbitMq server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromConsoleToRabbitFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(consoleSource(), c -> c.id("consoleInput")
                .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000))
                .autoStartup(true)
        ).channel("consoleOutputChannel")
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey("my_spring_integration_queue"))
                .get();
    }

    public MessageSource<String> consoleSource() {
        return CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource.stdin();
    }

}
```

It looks like almost working solution but I can't find `my_spring_integration_queue` in rabbitmq admin console:

[image]

But I can't find anything related to 'my_spring_integration_queue' on other tab. Where can I find it ?

I expect that application will create queue if it doesn't exist. I was not able to find a method for send into the queur so I used `.routingKey` method. I also tried `.exchangeName` method but it lead to the:

```
32019-08-27 13:26:15.972 ERROR 16372 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'my_spring_integration_queue' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

### P.S.

the Queue tab looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to add the queue manually or use a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean` to automatically declare it for you - the admin will find all beans of type `Queue` and declare them.

If you are using Spring Boot, it will automatically configure an admin bean for you so you just need the `Queue` `@Bean`.

See [Configuring the Broker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#broker-configuration).

Comment: Do I have to pass 2 parameters: exchange_name and routing_key? And I then I need somehow **bind** exchange and to the queue ?

Comment: It depends; all queues are bound to the default exchange with the queue name as the routing key. Or you can create an exchange and bind the queue with a routing key that is different to the queue name; then you must send to the exchange with the right routing key. I suggest you read the Spring AMQP reference manual and go though the [RabbitMQ tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) to learn more. The RabbitAdmin will find exchange and binding beans too - see the link in my answer.

Comment: Lets say I have queue with name **myQueue**. Do I have to write **.handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey("myQueue")** ? Do I have to pass any exchange?

Comment: As I said; yes that will work because `myQueue` is bound to the default exchange with its name as the routing key. The framework will send the message to the default exchange by default.